# AWS RDS / EC2: TimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm attempting to retrieve a User model from a `Node js 8.12.0` API, using `knex` and `bookshelf ORM`. Database is `Postgres 10.4`.

The API works fine locally, but hosted on ElasticBeanstalk EC2 and RDS, I get error:

> Unhandled rejection TimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a
>   connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a
>   .transacting(trx) call?

I'm able to connect and make queries to the RDS instance separately via connection string / password (it prompts for pw after I enter this):

```
psql -h myinstance.zmsnsdbakdha.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -d mydb -U myuser
```

Security Groups:

- The EC2 security group (set up by EB) is `sg-0fa31004bd2b763ce`, and RDS has an inbound security rule for PostgreSQL / TCP / port 5432 / for the matching source (`sg-0fa31004bd2b763ce`)— so it doesn't seem like the security group is a problem

RDS was created in a VPC, but the VPC's security rules are open too:

```
- security groups attached (multiple)
    - name: mysgname
    - group ID: sg-05d003b66fe1a4a94
    - Inbound rules: 
        - All Traffic (0.0.0.0/0) 
        - HTTP (80) for TCP (0.0.0.0/0) 
        - SSH (22) for TCP (0.0.0.0/0) 
        - PostgreSQL (5432) for TCP (0.0.0.0/0)
```

Publicly accessible: `Yes`

**users controller:**

```
router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    new User.User({'id': 1})
        .fetch({withRelated: ['addresses']})
        .then((user) => {
            res.send(user);
    });
});
```

**Knexfile:**

```
production: {
    client: 'pg',
    version: '7.2',
    connection: {
        host: process.env.PG_HOST || 'localhost',
        port: process.env.PG_PORT || '5432',
        user: process.env.PG_USER || 'myuser',
        password: process.env.PG_PASSWORD || '',
        database: process.env.PG_DB || 'mydb',
        charset: 'utf8',
    },
    pool: {
        min: 2,
        max: 20
    },
},
```

Firstly, why is this happening only on AWS hosted environment and not locally. Secondly, how can I fix this issue? Should I increase `max` for pools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your Network Access Control List (NACL) in your VPC and make sure your INBOUND and OUTBOUND are configured correctly. Security Groups are at the Instance level of security and the NACL is security at the Subnet level.

Most of the time when you are experiencing a Timeout error connecting to something in a custom VPC it will be a configuration problem with a Security Group or a NACL or Both.

Comment: For testing, the inbound Security Group rules for the VPC is pretty much wide open: https://i.imgur.com/G0HRqx3.png. Is this incorrect? If so, where can I find `NACL` on the VPC specifically?

Comment: Okay I found NACL— here are the listings for the subnets attached to the VPC: https://i.imgur.com/Vnq8QGT.png

Comment: Here is the NACL tab: https://i.imgur.com/mQCSi0a.png — it says "rule 100" allows all traffic, but `*` Denies (I'm guessing this is all others)

Comment: Add a Rull #200 for that port for both inbound and outbound, but I also noticed in your code above that you have the Security Group Configured for port 5432, and your code says 5433?

Comment: Sorry that `5433` was a typo in my SO post. Should be `5432`.

Comment: Error changed to `Unhandled rejection Error: Unable to acquire a connection`

Comment: Security settings on RDS instance: https://i.imgur.com/JQEsKq9.png, Configuration Settings: https://i.imgur.com/YF98Y94.png

Comment: @Growler This answer says your NACL and Secutiry Groups should be configured correctly, but how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I had a working code which was running in *heroku* instance. I have migrated to EBS and get stuck at this error for hours.
Heroku was setting `NODE_ENV=production` by default and i have corresponding configurations in my node.

But EBS does not set `NODE_ENV=production` by default  so my code was breaking.